# How to rotate a grid in wpf using Render Transform

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a grid with few controls inside it. I want to rotate it as if it looks like landscape mode. I am trying using below code :

```
    RotateTransform rt = RotateTransform (90);
    device.LayoutTransform=rt;
```

But it's not going to fully landscape rather it's rotating like 45 degree for any angle value.

Any Suggestion?

Comment: This is not clear what you're trying to do or where the problem lies, if you are just playing around with transforms read http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2008/12/19/layouttransform-vs-rendertransform-whats-the-difference.html for some background on layout versus render.

Comment: You're using `RotateTransform` like a method, but it's a class. Is that just a typo in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps:

```
private void AddRectangle() {
    Rectangle rotatedRectangle = new Rectangle();
    rotatedRectangle.Width = 200;
    rotatedRectangle.Height = 50;
    rotatedRectangle.Fill = Brushes.Blue;
    rotatedRectangle.Opacity = 0.5;
    RotateTransform rotateTransform1 = new RotateTransform(45, -50, 50);
    rotatedRectangle.RenderTransform = rotateTransform1;

    MyGridContainer.Children.Add(rotatedRectangle);
}
```